# Evaluation techniques for multicore processors with real time OS .. suggestions ?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, operating-system, real-time, evaluation

What would you suggest as a worthy evaluation technique in terms of worst case execution time (WCET) when running a real time OS on multicore processors  ?

Comment: A worthy evaluation technique would be to take all relevant variables into consideration. That's the best answer I can provide with the information you've given. Have you done any research at all on this topic? If so, then give us a little more information about your application and the hardware on which it's running. Is there disk I/O involved? Shared memory use? Heavy duty parallel processing? Or is it a producer/consumer application? There is no way to give you a blanket answer absent *some* indication of the type of application and hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me elaborate it a bit more: A cluster of more than one cores with a local private memory, which is shared between cores within the cluster. The call tree of one Runnable is a sequential code and can be parallelized using conventional techniques. Communication between the runnables is done with shared variables using a buffer to avoid locks and mutex etc. The evaluation will be done in terms of WCET.
Thats the brief overview.

Comment: Edit your question to add more detail. Give a clear picture of your proposed design. Otherwise your question is unanswerable.